# Drop a table in django with id

Tags: python, django, web

I need to drop a table in django using a model in code. After dropping a table, id of each record should start from 1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you'll get with the ORM is

```py
Model.objects.all().delete()
```

replace Model with your model name

or execute SQL query in database direct use truncate:

```sql
Truncate table XXX
```

> The table handler does not remember the last used AUTO_INCREMENT value, but starts counting from the beginning. This is true even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to truncate() table. Not sure how it going in python, but in mysql it will be a

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
```

u can find table name in `model._meta.db_table`

Comment: I googled the truncate command and it seems like there is no truncate command in django ORM.. I can delete all records using .all().delete(), but will this drop ids?

Comment: No, i tried to use Table.objects.all().delete(), but ids of the new records do not start from 1((